# single click and double click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have these functions that execute once a link is clicked.  For some reason though when the link is  clicked once it doesn't open.  You have to double-click. After the page has been visited it only requires the link to be clicked once.  How do I fix this so it only requires one click.

```js
function indexClick() {
  $("#home").on("click", function() {
    $('.indexPicWrapper').css('display', 'block');
    $('.aboutPicWrapper').css('display', 'none');
  })
}

function aboutClick() {

  $("#about").on("click", function() {
    $(".indexPicWrapper").css("display", "none")
    $('.contactPicWrapper').css('display', 'none');
    $('.aboutPicWrapper').css('display', 'block');
  })
}
```

```css
nav {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.indexPicWrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background: #FFA10D;
  position: absolute;
}
.aboutPicWrapper {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: #FF510D;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<nav>
  <a id="home" onclick="indexClick()" class="indexLink" href="#">Home</a>
  <a id="about" class="aboutLink" onclick="aboutClick()" href="#">About</a>
</nav>


<div class="indexPicWrapper">
  <h1>Things...</h1>
</div>

<div class="aboutPicWrapper">
  <h1>About...</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: add `return true;` to the end of event listeners, this will make the links perform their default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `event.preventDefault();` for click event and directly write `onclick` no need to write function

```js
$("#home").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.indexPicWrapper').css('display', 'block');
  $('.aboutPicWrapper').css('display', 'none');
})

$("#about").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  $(".indexPicWrapper").css("display", "none")
  $('.contactPicWrapper').css('display', 'none');
  $('.aboutPicWrapper').css('display', 'block');
})
```

```css
nav {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.indexPicWrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background: #FFA10D;
  position: absolute;
}
.aboutPicWrapper {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: #FF510D;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<nav>
  <a id="home" class="indexLink" href="#">Home</a>
  <a id="about" class="aboutLink" href="#">About</a>
</nav>


<div class="indexPicWrapper">
  <h1>Things...</h1>
</div>

<div class="aboutPicWrapper">
  <h1>About...</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are mixing up two ways to use the click event with javascript and one of its library jQuery.

Lets do this first with pure javascript.

***javascript :***

```
var indexPicWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("indexPicWrapper");
var aboutPicWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("aboutPicWrapper");
var contactPicWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("contactPicWrapper");

function indexClick(){
    indexPicWrapper[0].style.display = "block";
    aboutPicWrapper[0].style.display = "none";
}

function aboutClick(){
    indexPicWrapper[0].style.display = "none";
    aboutPicWrapper[0].style.display = "block";
    contactPicWrapper[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

[***jsFiddle - For javaScript***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/07dqmyou/)

Now if you prefer jQuery then you don't need to mention the onclick attribute in your HTML element, rather you just can use the click event of jQuery.

***jQuery :***

```
$("#home").on("click", function() {
    $('.indexPicWrapper').css('display', 'block');
    $('.aboutPicWrapper').css('display', 'none');
});

$("#about").on("click", function() {
    $(".indexPicWrapper").css("display", "none")
    $('.contactPicWrapper').css('display', 'none');
    $('.aboutPicWrapper').css('display', 'block');
});
```

[***jsFiddle - For jQuery***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/mrux3Lyn/)

Comment: "*...if you prefer jQuery then you don't need the onclick attribute attached with your HTML element*" - the `onclick` attribute is rarely, if ever, needed, with JavaScript or any of its libraries, so long as there's an alternate (better) means of identifying the specific element(s).